# ng-repeat on object angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object like this

```
Obj = {
  "elements":[
               {"name":"something","id":"v1-234"},
               {"name":"somethingElse","id":"v1-239"}
             ],
  "paging":{
    "next" : "100",
    "total": "2000"  
   },
 "linked"={
            "partners":[
                         {"id":"82","name":"A"},
                         {"id":"83","name":"B"}
                       ],
             "instructors":
                       [
                         {"id":"11232","name":"alex"},
                         {"id":"11432","name":"boob"}
                       ]
           }
    }
```

I have equal items inside the elements array and the partner and instructors array. I have only placed 2 items just for display there could be many.

The Obj.elements[0] is related to Obj.linked.partners[0] and Obj.linked.instructors[0]. Similarly for the first,second,third ..... items as well.

How can I ng-repeat on this object such that I can show

Obj.elements[i]  Obj.linked.partners[i]  Obj.linked.instructors[i]

at a time in html template ?

Comment: You will have to format your viewmodel to meet your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your elements, partners, and instructors arrays will always be the same length and you wanted to for example join together the names you could try something like this.

```
<div ng-repeat="element in Obj.elements">
    {{element.name}} {{Obj.linked.partners[$index].name}} {{Obj.linked.instructors[$index].name}}
</div>
```

$index is used by Angular in a ng-repeat to keep track of its position when iterating through an object. Here is the documentation: [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: I think `Obj.elemnts` would throw an error since it doesn't seem a valid `repeat_expression` (see docs) you should modify it in something like `ng-repeat="item in Obj.elements"` even if you don't use item

Comment: It wouldn't throw an error because Obj.elements is an array.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-repeat` has the `$index` scoped variable:

```
<ANY ng-repeat="element in model.elements">
   <span ng-bind="element.name"></span>
   <span ng-bind="model.linked.partners[$index].name"></span>
   <span ng-bind="model.linked.instructors[$index].name"></span>
</ANY>
```

Comment: I think the span should be `ng-bind=model.linked.[...]`

Comment: @drakyoko should be what? ;P